# Skywave Radio Propagation

Tags: radio

What physical laws govern the reflection and propagation of radio waves off of the ionosphere?  I am trying to locate papers, journals or experiments that have been devoted to studying this phenomenon.

Comment: The reflection of radiowaves is a consequence of the plasma present in the ionosphere. However maybe you could start here: [wikipedia ionosphere waveguide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%E2%80%93ionosphere_waveguide)

Comment: Did you even google this before asking??? I can find all kinds of reasons to close this, but insufficient effort is a really strong one.

Comment: I did google it, thanks, but the pages I found either assumed foundational knowledge or were Wikipedia, which is a nice starting place, but only that.

Comment: The Ham Radio Stackexchange might be a good place to ask instead. Skywave propagation is covered in one of the sets of licensing material for the US at least (I can't remember which one -likely either General or Extra, not Technician).

Comment: @JonCuster thank you. I will do that. This can be closed and thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 2):

No extra laws are needed. Everything you need can be derived from Maxwell's (or rather Heaviside's) Equations. Any reflection problem can be worked one of two ways:

1. Use physical optics, which taking the particle side of the EM energy and seeing how much gets reflected off of the boundary based on preset boundary conditions. Mainly, the tangential E field component must remain the same across boundaries.
2. Take the EM energy as a wave and use transmission line theory to solve for the reflection. The other side of the boundary (ionosphere) can be treated as a impedance mismatch, which always gives a reflection in TL Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Actually skywaves are not govern by diffent laws , all the E/M waves are explained pretty well by classical electrodynamics.
So if you want to study waves you should begin with classical ED and maybe with classical optics.